# Can slits in double slit experiment be substituted?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, experimental-technology

Can slits in double slit experiment be substituted with something material (rod, sphere, human hair...)?
This of course implies lack of walls.

It seems reasonable to me, as X-ray crystallography basically works because atoms (which are basically spherical) act as sources of spherical waves when hit by x-rays.

If someone is curious, I was thinking if it is possible to do double slit experiment with gravitational waves and a trio of galaxies or black holes, given that [they align correctly](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhenThePlanetsAlign) ;). But the question is general.

Comment: Do you mean take a classic slit experiment and replace the slit(s) with a solid line and the solid with air? Of course you can, and not surprisingly by superposition the sum of (pattern with slit + pattern with line) = 1 (where 1 is the intensity of the incident plane wave).

Comment: @JonCuster
"Do you mean take a classic slit experiment and replace the slit(s) with a solid line and the solid with air?" Yes, with exception that line is mathematical object, and I am think about real world material objects ; )
"Of course you can, and not surprisingly by superposition the sum of (pattern with slit + pattern with line) = 1 (where 1 is the intensity of the incident plane wave)." Why not make an answer out of it then?